# issue in sending email using outlook smtp with phpmailer class

Tags: php, outlook, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send email from outlook smtp using phpmailer class. I am getting the following error.

```
2017-07-18 09:19:33 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' =>                                          array ('verify_peer' => false,                                            'verify_peer_name' => false,                                            'allow_self_signed' => true,                                      ),
                                      )
2017-07-18 09:19:34 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
                                      error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol [/var/www/html/application/third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 294]
2017-07-18 09:19:34 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [/var/www/html/application/third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 294]
2017-07-18 09:19:34 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.office365.com:587 (Unknown error) [/var/www/html/application/third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php line 294]
2017-07-18 09:19:34 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
2017-07-18 09:19:34 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Can some one help me on this???

Answer (score 2):

In the time it took you to write this question, you could have clicked the link that's included in the error message which takes you a page that tells you how to fix this this exact error.

You can't use `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` with `Port = 587`; Set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`.